# Well-definedness of a resonant state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, nuclear-physics, atomic-physics

In nuclear physics, there is a famous state of the $^{12}$C, i.e., the [Hoyle state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon-12). It is a resonant state of $^{12}$C, with a finite lifetime. In the literature, people talk about its energy, size, wave function, etc.

I am confused at a basic point. A stable eigenstate of a system is well defined, so we can talk about its energy, size, wave function without any ambiguity.  But a resonance state is not well defined, right? If a wave function $\psi$ does not satisfy the Schrodinger equation $H\psi = E \psi$, with what principle are you going to pick it uniquely among its neighbors?

Comment: Nature is giving you a hint here that isolated wave functions are not everything. Why? Because atoms, nuclei etc. are not perfectly isolated systems. They interact with their environment through fields. If you want to talk about excited states "without ambiguity", then you would have to take the wave function of the environment (i.e. the "physical vacuum") into account as well. That can be done, but it gets complicated quickly and ultimately ends in us having to perform quantum field calculations. In most cases that's overkill.

Answer (score 3):

As you mention, states have a finite lifetime, $\tau$, which is related to the width in the energy of the state, $\Gamma$: $\Delta E \sim \frac{\hbar}{\tau} = \hbar \Gamma$. For stable states, the lifetime is very long and so the uncertainty in energy is very small ($\Gamma \approx 0$). For resonant states,  however, the finite width leads to a distribution in energy of the particle, $ p(E) \propto \frac{1}{(E − E_R)^2 + (\Gamma/2)^2}$, peaked about the resonant energy, $E_R$.

I would take a look at the discussion of Decay Distributions on p.352-355 of [Particle Physics (Martin & Shaw)](https://faculty.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/martin_-_particle_physics_3e_wiley_2008.pdf).